# JQuery XDSoft datetimepicker plugin deafultTime option doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

I'm trying to use the https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

This is the code:

```
var date_time_picker = $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    formatDate: 'd.m.Y',
    formatTime: 'H:i',
    startDate: '21.10.2018',
    minDate:'21.10.2018',
    maxDate:'27.10.2018',
    showSecond: false,
    step: 30,
    defaultTime: '08:00'
});

date_time_picker.val('2018/10/21 08:00');
```

When the page loads, the input value as show above, but when I click the box and the calendar pops-up, the time is set to 00:00:
[image: calendar]

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shakedk/xpvt214o/965164/

1. How can I make the 08:00 button to be selected?
2. If I Run an action that uses the datetimepicker element before I open the calendar, "00:00" is being used. If I run it after I open the calendar, "08:00" is being used. How can I make "08:00" default in all cases?

Comment: It seems they've got the same problem in their example. Can you confirm that? And is that possible to make a jsfiddle version of your problem?

Comment: @ColinCline added JSFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropping the `startDate` parameter seemed to work. There may be a conflict when using both `startDate` and `date_time_picker.val('...')` to preset a date.

Please have a look at the code below:

```js
  
  var date_time_picker = $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    formatDate: 'd.m.Y',
    formatTime: 'H:i',
    //startDate: '21.10.2018',
    minDate:'21.10.2018',
    maxDate:'27.10.2018',
    showSecond: false,
    step: 30,
    defaultTime: '08:00',
    onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
      print.innerHTML = $input.datetimepicker('getValue')
  }
});

date_time_picker.val('2018/10/21 08:00');

var print = document.getElementById('defautktimeand');
print.innerHTML = new Date(date_time_picker.val()).toString()
```

```css
.xdsoft_datetimepicker {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.506);
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 color: #333;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 padding: 8px;
 padding-left: 0;
 padding-top: 2px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 9999;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: none;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_rtl {
 padding: 8px 0 8px 8px;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker iframe {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 75px;
 height: 210px;
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
}

/*For IE8 or lower*/
.xdsoft_datetimepicker button {
 border: none !important;
}

.xdsoft_noselect {
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

.xdsoft_noselect::selection { background: transparent }
.xdsoft_noselect::-moz-selection { background: transparent }

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_inline {
 display: inline-block;
 position: static;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker * {
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_datepicker, .xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker {
 display: none;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_datepicker.active, .xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker.active {
 display: block;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_datepicker {
 width: 224px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 8px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_rtl .xdsoft_datepicker {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 8px;
 margin-left: 0;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_showweeks .xdsoft_datepicker {
 width: 256px;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker {
 width: 58px;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 8px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_rtl .xdsoft_timepicker {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 8px;
 margin-left: 0;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_datepicker.active+.xdsoft_timepicker {
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 3px
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_monthpicker {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label i,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_prev,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_next,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_today_button {
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label i {
 opacity: 0.5;
 background-position: -92px -19px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 9px;
 height: 20px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_prev {
 float: left;
 background-position: -20px 0;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_today_button {
 float: left;
 background-position: -70px 0;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_next {
 float: right;
 background-position: 0 0;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_next,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_prev ,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_today_button {
 background-color: transparent;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 border: 0 none;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 height: 30px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
 outline: medium none;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 text-indent: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: 20px;
 min-width: 0;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_prev,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_next {
 float: none;
 background-position: -40px -15px;
 height: 15px;
 width: 30px;
 display: block;
 margin-left: 14px;
 margin-top: 7px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_rtl .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_prev,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_rtl .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_next {
 float: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 14px;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_prev {
 background-position: -40px 0;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box {
 height: 151px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div {
 background: #f5f5f5;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-bottom-width: 0;
 height: 25px;
 line-height: 25px;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div > div:first-child {
 border-top-width: 0;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_today_button:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_next:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_prev:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label {
 display: inline;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9999;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px 3px;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #fff;
 float: left;
 width: 182px;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label:hover>span {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label:hover i {
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 30px;
 z-index: 101;
 display: none;
 background: #fff;
 max-height: 160px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select.xdsoft_monthselect{ right: -7px }
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select.xdsoft_yearselect{ right: 2px }
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #ff8000;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option {
 padding: 2px 10px 2px 5px;
 text-decoration: none !important;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option.xdsoft_current {
 background: #33aaff;
 box-shadow: #178fe5 0 1px 3px 0 inset;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_month {
 width: 100px;
 text-align: right;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar {
 clear: both;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_year{
 width: 48px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;

}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td > div {
 padding-right: 5px;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar th {
 height: 25px;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td,.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar th {
 width: 14.2857142%;
 background: #f5f5f5;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: right;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 25px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_showweeks .xdsoft_calendar td,.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_showweeks .xdsoft_calendar th {
 width: 12.5%;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar th {
 background: #f1f1f1;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_today {
 color: #33aaff;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_highlighted_default {
 background: #ffe9d2;
 box-shadow: #ffb871 0 1px 4px 0 inset;
 color: #000;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_highlighted_mint {
 background: #c1ffc9;
 box-shadow: #00dd1c 0 1px 4px 0 inset;
 color: #000;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_default,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_current,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div.xdsoft_current {
 background: #33aaff;
 box-shadow: #178fe5 0 1px 3px 0 inset;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_other_month,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_disabled,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div.xdsoft_disabled {
 opacity: 0.5;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
 cursor: default;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_other_month.xdsoft_disabled {
 opacity: 0.2;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div:hover {
 color: #fff !important;
 background: #ff8000 !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_current.xdsoft_disabled:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box>div>div.xdsoft_current.xdsoft_disabled:hover {
 background: #33aaff !important;
 box-shadow: #178fe5 0 1px 3px 0 inset !important;
 color: #fff !important;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_disabled:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div.xdsoft_disabled:hover {
 color: inherit !important;
 background: inherit !important;
 box-shadow: inherit !important;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_calendar th {
 font-weight: 700;
 text-align: center;
 color: #999;
 cursor: default;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_copyright {
 color: #ccc !important;
 font-size: 10px;
 clear: both;
 float: none;
 margin-left: 8px;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_copyright a { color: #eee !important }
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_copyright a:hover { color: #aaa !important }

.xdsoft_time_box {
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.xdsoft_scrollbar >.xdsoft_scroller {
 background: #ccc !important;
 height: 20px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
.xdsoft_scrollbar {
 position: absolute;
 width: 7px;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_rtl .xdsoft_scrollbar {
 left: 0;
 right: auto;
}
.xdsoft_scroller_box {
 position: relative;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.506);
 background: #000;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
 border-left: 1px solid #333;
 border-right: 1px solid #333;
 border-top: 1px solid #333;
 color: #ccc;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div {
 background: #0a0a0a;
 border-top: 1px solid #222;
 color: #999;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label {
 background-color: #000;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select {
 border: 1px solid #333;
 background: #000;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option:hover {
 color: #000;
 background: #007fff;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label > .xdsoft_select > div > .xdsoft_option.xdsoft_current {
 background: #cc5500;
 box-shadow: #b03e00 0 1px 3px 0 inset;
 color: #000;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_label i,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_prev,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_next,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_today_button {
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar th {
 background: #0a0a0a;
 border: 1px solid #222;
 color: #999;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar th {
 background: #0e0e0e;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_today {
 color: #cc5500;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_highlighted_default {
 background: #ffe9d2;
 box-shadow: #ffb871 0 1px 4px 0 inset;
 color:#000;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_highlighted_mint {
 background: #c1ffc9;
 box-shadow: #00dd1c 0 1px 4px 0 inset;
 color:#000;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_default,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td.xdsoft_current,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div.xdsoft_current {
 background: #cc5500;
 box-shadow: #b03e00 0 1px 3px 0 inset;
 color: #000;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar td:hover,
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_timepicker .xdsoft_time_box >div >div:hover {
 color: #000 !important;
 background: #007fff !important;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_calendar th {
 color: #666;
}

.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_copyright { color: #333 !important }
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_copyright a { color: #111 !important }
.xdsoft_datetimepicker.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_copyright a:hover { color: #555 !important }

.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_time_box {
 border: 1px solid #333;
}

.xdsoft_dark .xdsoft_scrollbar >.xdsoft_scroller {
 background: #333 !important;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .xdsoft_save_selected {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd !important;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #454551;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .blue-gradient-button {
 font-family: "museo-sans", "Book Antiqua", sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #82878c;
 height: 28px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 4px 17px 4px 33px;
 border: 1px solid #d7d8da;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f4f8fa 73%);
 /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fff), color-stop(73%, #f4f8fa));
 /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f4f8fa 73%);
 /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f4f8fa 73%);
 /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f4f8fa 73%);
 /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #f4f8fa 73%);
 /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fff', endColorstr='#f4f8fa',GradientType=0 );
/* IE6-9 */
}
.xdsoft_datetimepicker .blue-gradient-button:hover, .xdsoft_datetimepicker .blue-gradient-button:focus, .xdsoft_datetimepicker .blue-gradient-button:hover span, .xdsoft_datetimepicker .blue-gradient-button:focus span {
  color: #454551;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f4f8fa 0%, #FFF 73%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f4f8fa), color-stop(73%, #FFF));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f8fa 0%, #FFF 73%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f4f8fa 0%, #FFF 73%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f4f8fa 0%, #FFF 73%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f4f8fa 0%, #FFF 73%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f4f8fa', endColorstr='#FFF',GradientType=0 );
  /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>  

<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">
<div id=defautktimeand>

</div>
```

Comment: Fixed the problem - thanks!
Though I still encounter strange things with the plugin. If I add 
`defaultDate: '21.10.2018',` with the formats specified above, I get errors. 
Only If I change it to `format: d.m.Y H:i` it works.

Also, pay attention that `date_time_picker.datetimepicker('getValue')` returns null if you call it for the default value, so your solution of using `new Date(datetimepicker.val())` always works